# How to read from Nutch segments without readseg command

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I'm using Nutch to crawl some websites, exactly I am crawling [this site](http://hendrix-http.cps.unizar.es/recinfo/recordsdc.html).

I have got [these five segments](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhSXcxdlPTbTiEXR2irnl9QozFvi) with all the documents found (around 10.000 documents). Now I want to process the content of the documents **without** using the `readseg` command, this is, not dumping the segments into plain text.

For this, only the subdirectory `content` of each segment is useful for me (the tags and the content of the document).

I have realised that inside the `content` directory there are two more containers: `data` and `index`. However I haven't found any explanation of them, and how can I read them to process the content inside. I have also found some [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699305/how-to-read-nutch-content-from-java-scala) to this question, but I have not yet understood the algorithm idea.

How is the content stored in a Nutch segment, and how can it be read? I have given the collection website and segments if a short example wants to be given (but not necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need to do with the content? you could for instance write a custom IndexWriter. It would be invoked during the indexing step and would give you access to the content. Alternatively look at the 'dump' command (org.apache.nutch.tools.FileDumper) and modify the code.

BTW 'Hadoop the Definitive Guide' by Tom White has a nice chapter on the Nutch data structures.

If you want to do further processing of the pages, like NLP or classification, [Behemoth](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/behemoth) can be used to convert Nutch segments into a 'neutral' datastucture on HDFS which can then be processed with various tools.

Answer (score 0):

According to @JulienNioche response, this has been my implementation.

```
// file is the root directory of the segments.
private static void indexSegments(File file)
        throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    // Do not try to index files that cannot be read.
    if (file.canRead() & file.isDirectory()) {
        // List with all the segments.
        File[] segmentDirs = file.listFiles();
        if (segmentDirs == null) {
            System.err.println("No segment directories found in '" +
                                file.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
            return;
        }
        Configuration conf = NutchConfiguration.create();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        // Index all the segments.
        for (File segment : segmentDirs) {
            /* Only the content of the documents managed in
             * the segment is useful for the system. */
            String segmentData = segment.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                    Content.DIR_NAME + "/part-00000/data";
            if (!new File(segmentData).exists()) {
                System.out.println("Skipping segment: '" + segment.getName() +
                                   "': no data directory present.");
                continue;
            }
            SequenceFile.Reader reader =
                    new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, new Path(segmentData), conf);
            Writable key = (Writable) reader.getKeyClass().newInstance();
            // Index all the documents managed in the current segment.
            while (reader.next(key)) {
                Content content = new Content();
                reader.getCurrentValue(content);
                String url = key.toString();
                String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url);
                String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(url);
                // Skips the document if it's not a XML file.
                String mimeType = new Tika().detect(content.getContent());
                if (mimeType == null | !mimeType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.toString())) {
                    System.out.println("Skipping document: '" + baseName +
                                       "': not a XML file.");
                    continue;
                }
                /* Content of the document. */
                ByteArrayInputStream bas = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getContent());
                int n = bas.available();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
                bas.read(bytes, 0, n);
                bas.close();
                String docContent = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                // TODO: Do what you want with the content.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old Q but I stumbled on it while trying to find an answer to the same Q.  I have scoured a few answers to come up with this simple java loop to fetch segment content.  The key class is the org.apache.hadoop.io.MapFile.Reader which reads index and data files.  Disclaimer I am new to nutch and hadoop but this works for me.

```
private void readContent(Path[] segmentPaths) throws Exception {
    
    String[] fileTypes = {"content", "crawl_fetch", "parse_data", "parse_text"};
    String partR = "part-r-00000";
    
    for (Path path : segmentPaths) {
        for (String type : fileTypes) {
            Path file = new Path(path, type + "/" + partR);
            MapFile.Reader reader = new MapFile.Reader(file, conf);
            
            WritableComparable key = (WritableComparable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getKeyClass(), conf);
            Writable value = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getValueClass(), conf);
            while (reader.next(key, value)) {
                System.out.printf("%s\t%s\n", key, value);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        
    }
}
```